# strange jQuery behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have created this menu icons. When you mouse over a text shows. The strange behaviour is that on the first icon the text show automatically instead of being open after hover on it. And when you hover it disappear, where the behaviour should be vice-versa.

I tried testing it in fiddle and it works fine
http://fiddle.jshell.net/largan/wLWpw/1/

I am attaching on fiddle also the behaviour on the website

The source in fiddle is identical with the source on the website.

**PROBLEM AND SOLUTION FOUND**

I found that only the first element got style="display: none; assigned.
I have created a fake #noshow id and added it as a first DIV so the style="display: none; is assigned to it.

I am quite sure that this is not the best approach but until I get better :) it will serve well.

Thanks for all the comments... somehow it helped :)

Comment: Can you describe your issue a little better. It's not clear at the moment what you mean.

Comment: In the example you can see the working example and a screenshot from the website when you load the website it automatically opens the hover div on the first icon

Comment: There must be something else on the website - can you provide a link?

Comment: @largan You are not hiding `#monster0` by default as you do for other relative elements in `style.css` file. Anyway, you'd have better to use some common class instead of all these IDs

Comment: well, I think that everything with the DOM is correct

Comment: @ A. Wolff, what do you mean? the display:none; is also declared for #monster0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in your css file. I added the actual css you use to your fiddle and it doesn't work. I narrowed it down to your comments //END BIG ICONS etc. I'd remove these. You also have a typo in dicplay:block;